# How can I add onClickListener to each ImageView separately?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, onclicklistener

I have programmatically added a Linear Layout in Android and added ImageViews to it. I used the following code for the same.

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear1);     
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    imagev = new ImageView(this);
    imagev.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(300,150));
    imagev.setMaxHeight(600);
    imagev.setMaxWidth(600);
    layout.addView(imagev);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i were to implement this, i would give each of the imageviews a specific tag, and then set the same onClickListener to each imageview. Then in the onClickListener, i would check the tag for the imageview that was clicked and do an action depending on whatever imageview was clicked.

```
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear1);     
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        imagev = new ImageView(this);
        imagev.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(300,150));
        imagev.setMaxHeight(600);
        imagev.setMaxWidth(600);
        imagev.setTag(i);
        imagev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 switch(Integer.valueOf(v.getTag())) {
                      case 0: ...
                              break;
                      case 1: ...
                              break;
                 }
            } 
        layout.addView(imagev);
    }
```

This would avoid having to have 4 different onClickListener, and give you some cleaner code.

Comment: Yes, this is a more elegant approach!

Comment: @Kasper it has some error in line “switch(Integer.valueOf(v.getTag))“ . error is “getTag cannot be resolved or is not a field“ please help.

Comment: That's supposed to be a function call, not a variable call, i made an error in the original code. Change 'v.getTag' to 'v.getTag()' and test it out.

Comment: @Kasper thanks..its working just changed “switch(Integer.valueOf(v.getTag())) {“    to   “switch((Integer) v.getTag()) {“

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
myClickListener1 = new View.OnClickListener ...
myClickListener2 ...
myClickListener3 ...
myClickListener4 ...

for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    imagev = new ImageView(this);
    imagev.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(300,150));
    imagev.setMaxHeight(600);
    imagev.setMaxWidth(600);
    switch(i){
            case 0: imagev.setOnClickListener(myClickListener1);
            break;
            case 1: ...
            ...
    }
    layout.addView(imagev);
}
```